# std::mutex can't be shared among std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14

In the following codes I suppose mLooperMutex can't be acquired by the children thread. But the program output is quite surprising. It looks that mLooperMutex captured in the std::thread is not the same one in main thread.

But if I changed the detach() call of std::thread to join(), this will lead to a deadlock since the mLooperMutex has been locked by the main thread.

Are there anything wrong with this program if I'd like to use the mLooperMutex among different threads?

> a.out:
>     main: wait cond begin
>     child: acquiring lock begin
>     child: acquiring lock done
>     child: notify one begin
>     child: notify one done
>     main: wait cond done

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::condition_variable looperSet;
    bool child_done = false;
    std::mutex mLooperMutex;

    cout << "main: acquiring lock begin" << endl;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mLooperMutex);
    cout << "main: acquiring lock done" << endl;

    std::thread{[&mutex=mLooperMutex, &looperSet, &child_done] () {
        cout << "child: acquiring lock begin" << endl;
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
        cout << "child: acquiring lock done" << endl;
        child_done = true;
        lock.unlock();

        cout << "child: notify one begin" << endl;
        looperSet.notify_one();
        cout << "child: notify one done" << endl;


    }}.detach();

    cout << "main: wait cond begin" << endl;
    looperSet.wait(lock, [&child_done]{ return child_done; });
    cout << "main: wait cond done" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the `mLooperMutex` can be acquired in the child thread is because the lock is released by `looperSet.wait`:

```
// This unlocks "lock", and then locks it again afterwards.
looperSet.wait(lock, [&child_done]{ return child_done; });
```

The reason why this doesn't work with `.join()` is because `.join()` waits for the thread to finish before proceeding, and the thread can't finish until the lock is released, and `looperSet.wait()` which releases the lock won't run until `.join()` finishes.

Creating a thread and then immediately calling `.join()` is not very useful, you might as well run the code directly rather than using a thread.